# PHP - Replace values of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, replace

i have this code:

```
$mainArray = Array(
[0] => Array
    (            
        [0] => 06
    )

[1] => Array
    (            
        [0] => 15
    )    
)
$array1 = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"); 
$array2 = array_reverse($array1);
```

I wanna replace the values of $mainArray recursivelly with value of $array2 (for example, when in the $mainArray has values equal 15 replace with 5, 6 replace with 14.

I've tried with:

```
foreach($mainArray $k1 => $value1){
    foreach($value1 as $k2 => $value2){ 

        $value2 = str_replace($array1,$array2,$value2);

        echo $value2;
    }
 }
```

But not work correctly.

Comment: Can you explain more specifically what determines what the replacement values should be?

Answer (score 0):

Find index in the 1st array, and take value from the 2nd

```
$value2 = $array2[array_search($value2, $array1)];
```

Or if an algorithm is always the same

```
$max = 20;
$value2 = $max - $value2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not need the other arrays to do this. If I understand the replacement strategy properly, you can do it mathematically instead by just subtracting the original value from 20 to get the replacement value.

```
$replaced = array_map(function($x) {
    return array(20 - $x[0]);
}, $mainArray);
```